# jQuery: Show/hide alert based on element visibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on a job listings page that shows results based on the combination of various filters. I want a "No matches" message to appear when there are no results for a set of filters, and I figured I'd just show/hide a `p` element via a `click` function based on the visibility of the job listing elements. Each job listing is contained within an `li.requisition-item`; and I tried to test in two different ways for visibility based on other SO threads. This is what I have thus far:

```
$(".requisition-filter a").on("click", function() {

    if ($('.requisition-item').is(":visible").length == 0 || $('.requisition-item').css('display') == 'none' ) {
        $('p.no-results').show();
        console.log('show alert');
    }
    else if ( $('.requisition-item').is(":visible").length || $('.requisition-item').css('display') == 'block' ) {
        $('p.no-results').hide();
        console.log('hide alert');
    }
    else {
        $('p.no-results').hide();
    }
});
```

Thus, I have a paragraph element with the class `no-results` that should show/hide based on these conditions, but it the script does not behave as expected. The alert will (sometimes) show properly, but not "re-hide" appropriately when the filters reveal listings again. Any ideas what's going wrong here?

Comment: A bit off-topic, but your web site is beautiful. I like the design

Comment: `.is(":visible")` returns a boolean, either true or false, which has no length

Comment: @adeneo is correct, maybe you should replace .is with .filter then use .length

Comment: If you don't need the logs, you can just do `$('p.no-results').toggle( $('.requisition-item').is(":visible") )`

Comment: thanks for the responses-- @adeneo, would I just replace the entire `if` statement with the `toggle` method you've described?

Comment: Yes, replace everything inside the click function and see if that works the way you wanted to.

Comment: @adeneo - hm, just tried the `toggle` method and it still seems to be behaving strangely... seems like jQuery is not properly detecting the visibility of the items. Any other ideas?

Comment: How does it behave strangely?

Comment: @adeneo when clicking on "Russia" for example, 2 listings will show, but the `p.no-results` element will also show, when it should be hidden-- still can't seem to figure out why the visibility of the `.requisition-items` is not properly registering when the `click` function is fired...

Answer (score 1):

In the attached solution, I faked the filtering out of items just by clicking the 'Filter out items' button (same as if I was clicking Russia). This runs a check for if any of the results are visible, and displays the no results message accordingly.

```js
$("button.filter").click(function() {
  $(".item").toggle();
  checkResults();
});

function checkResults() {
  var $items = $(".item");

  if ($items.filter(":visible").length == 0) {
    $(".message").show();
  } else {
    $(".message").hide();
  }
}
```

```css
.message {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  left: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="message">No results!</div>
<button class="filter">Filter out items</button>
<ul>
  <li class="item">Item 1</li>
  <li class="item">Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, @Passersby, I will try your approach and report back!